# NS_ENUM vs enum

Tags: objective-c

Objective C provides several ways to declare an enumeration. It could be declared via `typedef enum` or `NS_ENUM`. `NS_ENUM` macro takes type name as a parameter, and I do not completely understand its meaning. I didn't find description of `NS_ENUM` macro in official Apple documentation. What's a difference between using `enum` and `NS_ENUM`? And an other question if it's possible to use any other type in `NS_ENUM` instead `NSInteger` and its relative integer types?

Answer (score 13):

NSHipster provided a very nice post that explains this thoroughly:

http://nshipster.com/ns_enum-ns_options/

To quote the bottom line:

> > This approach combines the best of all of the aforementioned approaches (enum, typedef enum), and even provides hints to the compiler for **type-checking** and **switch statement completeness**.

Answer (score 10):

The main difference is that `typedef NS_ENUM` translates to a Swift enum properly, whereas `typedef enum` doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the link to the official Apple's documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ModernizationObjC/AdoptingModernObjective-C/AdoptingModernObjective-C.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014150-CH1-SW6

From the subsection titled "Enumeration Macros":

> The `NS_ENUM` and `NS_OPTIONS` macros provide a concise, simple way of defining enumerations and options in C-based languages. These macros improve code completion in Xcode and explicitly specify the type and size of your enumerations and options. Additionally, this syntax declares enums in a way that is evaluated correctly by older compilers, and by newer ones that can interpret the underlying type information.
>
> Use the `NS_ENUM` macro to define *enumerations*, a set of values that are mutually exclusive:
>
> ```
> typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UITableViewCellStyle) {
>         UITableViewCellStyleDefault,
>         UITableViewCellStyleValue1,
>         UITableViewCellStyleValue2,
>         UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
> };
> ```
>
> The `NS_ENUM` macro helps define both the name and type of the enumeration, in this case named `UITableViewCellStyle` of type `NSInteger`. The type for enumerations should be `NSInteger`.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged. If there is useful information available, you should make it a part of your answer.

Comment: @Sahuagin If you look at the question carefully, finding the link to the official documentation is a part of it.